# removing an observer fails

Tags: ios, observers

in my app I add an observer in a ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self
                                            forKeyPath:@"messagesBadge"
                                               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                               context:NULL];
}
```

..and clean it up afterwards.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"messagesBadge" context:NULL];
}
```

However, the app crashes on **viewWillDisappear**, logging:

> 'Cannot remove an observer **myViewController 0x78efa160** for the key
>   path "messagesBadge" from **NSUserDefaults 0x78e27f20** because it is
>   not registered as an observer.'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try put it on `dealloc` instead, also check if you already remove it elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

I could remove this question, but maybe it is helpful to others:

The crash happened only the **second** time around when **viewWillDisappear** was called.

So, I moved the addObserver from **viewDidLoad** to **viewWillAppear**. That fixed it.

Comment: Perfecto! I don't understand how this solution works .Can you explain?